# Ffmpeg rotate drawtext with hwaccel

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I trying to draw several texts on a raw video. One of the texts is watermark and it should be diagonal.

My previous command to draw 2 horizantal texts. This command works with 246 fps

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -y -r 25 -f h264 -hwaccel nvdec -i input -vf 
"drawtext=text='Bottom Center':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-3:
fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=125:fontcolor=9BBB59@0.65:
box=1:boxcolor=8064A2@0.74:boxborderw=5,
drawtext=text='Top Center':x=(W-tw)/2:y=3:
fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=72:fontcolor=4F81BD@1:
box=1:boxcolor=C0504D@1:boxborderw=5" 
-c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4
```

But after i add diagonal watermark text fps drops to 25.

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -y -r 25 -f h264 -hwaccel nvdec -i input -filter_complex 
"color=black@0:100x100,format=yuva420p[c];[c]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,
drawtext=text='WATERMARK   WATERMARK   WATERMARK':x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2:
fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=(w+h)/18:fontcolor=FFFFFF@0.2,
split[txt][alpha],[txt][alpha]alphamerge,
rotate=(-27*PI)/180:ow=rotw((-27*PI)/180):oh=roth((-27*PI)/180):c=black@0[rot];
[mv][rot]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:shortest=1,
drawtext=text='Bottom Center':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-3:
fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=125:fontcolor=9BBB59@0.65:
box=1:boxcolor=8064A2@0.74:boxborderw=5,
drawtext=text='Top Center':x=(W-tw)/2:y=3:
fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=72:fontcolor=4F81BD@1:
box=1:boxcolor=C0504D@1:boxborderw=5" 
-c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4
```

Why `hwaccel nvdec` and `c:v h264_nvenc` does not work for second command?
Is 25 fps expected result for rotation?

Results belong to FFmpeg 4.1.3, Windows 10 and NVIDIA Quadro RTX 5000

I tried FFmpeg 5.0.1, fps increases 25 to ~40. But FFmpeg 5.0.1 requires to update gpu driver.

Comment: You may try drawing the rotated WATERMARK on a PNG image (from advance), and overlay the PNG image over the video.

Comment: @Rotem Texts and resolution of raw video are not predefined. Actually i can create bitmap image in program runtime then save and use it but i need resolution of raw video.

Comment: For creating the rotated text PNG image, try: `ffmpeg -y -f h264 -hwaccel nvdec -i input -filter_complex "color=black@0:100x100,format=yuva420p[c];[c]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=text='WATERMARK   WATERMARK  WATERMARK':x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=(w+h)/18:fontcolor=FFFFFF@0.2,split[txt][alpha],[txt][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=(-27*PI)/180:ow=rotw((-27*PI)/180):oh=roth((-27*PI)/180):c=black@0[rot];[mv]nullsink" -frames:v 1 -map "[rot]" rot_text.png`

Comment: @Rotem Thanks. Overlaying the PNG over the video is faster than drawing. I tried with the video that has 1920x1080 resolution but image was 2201x1834. Is it normal ? Can i also add horizantal texts to PNG ?

Comment: Changed `ow=rotw((-27*PI)/180):oh=roth((-27*PI)/180)` to `ow=iw:oh=ih` and it solved resolution. Then added `[rot]_horizantal drawtext_[fin]` before `;[mv]nullsink` and changed `-map "[rot]"` to  `-map "[fin]"`. If you want add answer, then i can mark it.

Comment: I added an example that uses `-c:v h264_cuvid` and `overlay_cuda` at the bottom. In my machine it improved the fps from 200 to 300. The command requires FFmpeg 5.01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may create an overlaid PNG image from advance, and overlay the PNG image on top of the video.

Assuming the rotating operation takes a relatively long time, the suggested solution applies the rotation only once instead of applying the rotation for each frame.

Example for preparing the overlaid PNG image:

`ffmpeg -y -f h264 -hwaccel nvdec -i input.264 -filter_complex "color=black@0:100x100,format=rgba[c];[c]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=text='WATERMARK   WATERMARK  WATERMARK':x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=(w+h)/18:fontcolor=FFFFFF@0.2,split[txt][alpha],[txt][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=(-27*PI)/180:ow=iw:oh=ih:c=black@0,drawtext=text='Bottom Center':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-3:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=125:fontcolor=9BBB59@0.65:box=1:boxcolor=8064A2@0.74:boxborderw=5,drawtext=text='Top Center':x=(W-tw)/2:y=3:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=72:fontcolor=4F81BD@1:box=1:boxcolor=C0504D@1:boxborderw=5[fin];[mv]nullsink" -frames:v 1 -map "[fin]" rot_text.png`

- `scale2ref` is used for adjusting the resolution of the image to the resolution of the video.
- `[mv]nullsink` is used for ignoring `[mv]` "unconnected" output stream.
- `-frames:v 1` - stops after the first frame.

Example for overlaying the PNG image over the video:

`ffmpeg.exe -y -r 25 -f h264 -hwaccel nvdec -i input -i rot_text.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" -c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4`

---

Testing:

Build synthetic pattern for testing (apply low resolution 192x108 for example):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=10:duration=10 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f h264 input.264`

Build `rot_text.png` image:

`ffmpeg -y -f h264 -hwaccel nvdec -i input.264 -filter_complex "color=black@0:100x100,format=rgba[c];[c]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=text='WATERMARK   WATERMARK  WATERMARK':x=(W-tw)/2:y=(H-th)/2:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=(w+h)/18:fontcolor=FFFFFF@0.8,split[txt][alpha],[txt][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=(-27*PI)/180:ow=iw:oh=ih:c=black@0,drawtext=text='Bottom Center':x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-th-3:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=12:fontcolor=9BBB59@0.65:box=1:boxcolor=8064A2@0.74:boxborderw=5,drawtext=text='Top Center':x=(W-tw)/2:y=3:fontfile=arial.ttf:fontsize=7:fontcolor=4F81BD@1:box=1:boxcolor=C0504D@1:boxborderw=5[fin];[mv]nullsink" -frames:v 1 -map "[fin]" rot_text.png`

[image]

Overlay the image on `input.264`:

`ffmpeg -y -r 25 -f h264 -hwaccel nvdec -i input.264 -i rot_text.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" -c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4`

Sample output frame:
[image]

---

Moving more work to the GPU - using `overlay_cuda`:

The following command moves more work to the GPU (hoping to improve the performance):

`ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -init_hw_device cuda=cuda -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -r 25 -f h264 -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.264 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i rot_text.png -filter_complex "[1]hwupload_cuda[rot];[0]scale_cuda=format=yuv420p[vid];[vid][rot]overlay_cuda=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" -c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4`

The above command requires updated FFmpeg version (i.e. FFmpeg 5.01).